# How to call one small javascript chunks of code instead of call one big bundle.js?

Tags: reactjs

in REACTJS, is there a way to just call javascript chunks of code that contains needed components on one specific page instead of call one big bundle.js containing all components of the webapp?

Comment: You will need to use something like Webpack for code splitting: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: You can just bundle them separately. The reason it's usually bundled all into one JS file is for convenience and so everything is in one place. If you're needing to use/embed scripts separately then in your build process divide them up into all the parts that need to be distinct